An analytic number theory problem on Competition of Shuzhimi
I'm a number theory enthusiast. Now I'm working on a problem of Shuzhimi Competition (谜之竞赛 in Chinese). It looks like an analytic number theory problem and it's extremely hard. It's the Problem 7 of Competition of Shuzhimi, June 2023 and the proposer of this problem is Mucong Sun. The problem is:
Let an integer $k \geq 2$, $f$ and $g$ non-constant polynomials with positive leading coefficient. We say a positive integer $n$ is "Good" if $f(n) \mid k^{g(n)}-1$. Prove that for any integer $n>3$, the "Good" numbers in $[1,n]$ are less than $\frac{c n \ln \ln n}{\ln n}$ for some positive $c$.
My classmate told me that it's a sieve problem, but I don't know how to solve it. Please help me

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some work of your own in order to get help. I suggest you edit your question to include your efforts to avoid the downvoting and eventual closing of your question.

@jjagmath Reasonable response.  Personally, I advocate relaxing the protocol for expired contest problems because : [1] It is very plausible that the problem solver is completely untrained for the problem, and thus can not reasonably be expected to either list the applicable tools, discuss solving strategies, or show work.  [2] The motivation is built-in; the problem solver is attempting to prepare for contest math, where no pertinent class course work is available.

@jjagmath In effect, it is very plausible that the problem solver would have to get professional advice on which book or books to study to obtain a reasonable mastery of the corresponding math topic, in order to have developed a reasonable arsenal of pertinent tools.  Such an approach, that is tailored to the math subject rather than the specific math problem, might well take several months of self-study, which does not seem like a reasonable request on the part of MathSE reviewers.
